# Powershell - Retrieve inner exception to output (socketException)

Tags: .net, powershell, exception, error-handling

I have recently started digging into error handling in Powershell and I noticed something that I do not really understand (I cannot tell where this behaviour is coming from).

I have a simple function, which checks for domain name using `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName()`

If this variable gets passed a non-existing host, it throws a nasty error

`Exception calling "GetHostByName" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known"`

I then want to catch the error and do some cosmetics around it

`$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` gives a really nice output:

`No such host is known`

and nothing else - which I like, and I want it to be the message appearing instead of error.

When I place the above in the catch clause, everything works fine.

But how surprised I was when I saw that putting semicolons, or using `Write-host` or in any way converting that to 'string' value, messes up the innerException.

Try it for yourself:

- cause a SocketException using the 'wrong' name
- See what `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` throws
- See what `"$($Error[0].Exception.InnerException)"` throws

The first command gives the `No such host is known` while the second command gives the complete error.
Please explain me why is this happening?

Finally, I would want the error message to popup:

`No such host is known: $computername`. Is there 'easy' way to do this rather than doing bloody regular expressions?

Comment: @AbhineetVerma British English is perfectly valid. If you're going to suggest spelling changes learn that *behaviour* is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the difference is which method Powershell is calling to get the output from the object in different circumstances.

When you just output it to the pipeline by using

```
$error[0].exception.innerexception
```

it's calling the `.GetBaseException()` method, which just outputs the Message property.

When you cast it as [string] to use with Write-Host, it's calling the `.tostring()` method, which is outputting all of the error information.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer and an explanation. If for couple of hours no in-depth answer appear, this will do as an explanation :-) For future it will be important to remember with what type of exception I am dealing with (`$Error[0].Exception.GetBaseException().GetType() | Select -ExpandProperty Name`)

Comment: It is not true that it just outputs "Message" property.   
You can test by running ```[ADSI]"LDAP://fake.server:636"``` to generate an error.   
The output from ```$Error[0].InnerException.GetBaseException()``` is:  
```The server is not operational.```  
The output from ```$Error[0].InnerException.Message``` is:  
```The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName":  
 "The server is not operational."```

Answer (score 2):

this?

```
"$($Error[0].Exception.InnerException.message): $computername"
```

The behaviour you have IMHO is due to the [custom formatting file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Kind of 'awful' I missed yet another subproperty, I wanted to stick the first thing which was giving me what I was looking for. Nontheless, it seems that not the formatting is the issue, but what @mjolinor wrote to be the issue. It is one of the few not-straightforward for me things in Powershell :-)

Comment: Actually, I think this answer is arguably as "right" as the one I posted. Outputting to an empty pipeline is going to send it to Out-Default, and the .ps1xml file may well be where it's getting told to call the .GetBaseException() method.  Either way you've figured out the right way to solve the problem - check your object type and look at it's properties and methods to see what your options are, then choose your weapon.