# Downloading files with powershell 2.0 on windows 7

Tags: powershell-2.0, download

Here's my script to download the file, im replacing the url to download from because it's a private cloud site, i've searched everywhere and they all say that this is the right way to download in older versions of PS but i keep getting the error

> `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." At line:60 char:25    +     $client.DownloadFile <<<< ($url, $targetFile)     + CategoryInfo     : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

```
$url = "(download url)" 
$path = "C:\temp\jre-7u71-windows-i586.exe" 
# param([string]$url, [string]$path) 

if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent $path))) { 
  $targetFile = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path) 
} 

"Downloading [$url]`nSaving at [$path]" 
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$client.DownloadFile($url, $targetFile) 
#$client.DownloadData($url, $targetFile) 

$path
```

Comment: You've written out $url and $targetFile, or used a breakpoint or something and the variables are as you expect?

Comment: Most likely a privileges issue with your $targetFile. To know what is wrong though, you need to get the inner exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651213/powershell-retrieve-inner-exception-to-output-socketexception

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and there seems to be a problem in the way you declared your $client variable.

Old post, but this works for me in Windows 7, PowerShell 2.0

Please note that URL and Path are changed.

```
$url = "http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1604.exe" 
$path = "C:\temp\7z1604.exe" 
# param([string]$url, [string]$path) 

if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent $path))) { 
$targetFile = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path) 
} 

(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $path) 
$path
```