# Downloading files with powershell 2.0 on windows 7 - From Microsoft

Tags: powershell, file, download, windows-7

I'm trying to automate the download of MSE definition files from Microsoft using powershell on Win7. *I'm looking for a poweshell script that will do this.*

I cannot use the Windows Update service or BITS service as both of these are disabled to prevent the OS from automatically downloading updates that break the computer. MSE uses the update service to get new definitions.

I have a script (below) **working** for regular files hosted using https. E.G. https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1604.exe

When I use a Microsoft download URL (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341), the script fails with this error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying
> connecti on was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." At
> C:\temp\run.ps1:9 char:40

Microsoft don't use regular https or ftp file links for some reason. I don't know what sort of link they use, but they don't work with the script below. It's not a https certificate problem either. Files from https sources work just fine:

```
$url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341" 
$path = "C:\temp\update.exe" 
# param([string]$url, [string]$path) 

if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent $path))) { 
$targetFile = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path) 
} 

(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $path) 
$path
```

I got the above script from this link:
[Downloading files with powershell 2.0 on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523709/downloading-files-with-powershell-2-0-on-windows-7)

I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [this blog](https://hodgkins.io/download-file-with-powershell-without-renaming) from Matthew Hodgkins?  Just from briefly looking at it, it seems very similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just tried to run the script, but it errors at line 16. = operator missing after named argument. Mailed the author for clarification.

Comment: I don't have your environment/situation.  So I don't know if my answer will work for you.  If it doesn't, then maybe it is close enough we can still get it working with a small change.  For example, `-1` for `Segments[-1]` might not work and we might have to explicitly point to the last segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function, which works in both PS v5.1 and PS v7.2.x, uses `Invoke-WebRequest` for downloading Microsoft links of the format `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=idNumber` by first checking if the file name can be retrieved from `Content-Disposition` (As described in Matthew Hodgkins [blog](https://hodgkins.io/download-file-with-powershell-without-renaming)), and, if that fails, then attempts to extract the file name from `BaseResponse` by determining its type and extracting the URI from the appropriate location.

If the code fails to determine the file name, it attempts to save the file with the file name `Dowloaded.File`, but this isn't tested and shouldn't be trusted. Throwing an error is likely.

**NOTE:** While this does work for the 3 example links in the code, the nature of this code is such that one should expect it to work for some links while failing for others.  If anyone finds a failing link, and places it in the comments, I might be able figure how to extract the proper file name and modify the function to deal with it correctly.

```
function Invoke-WebRequestDownload {
    [OutputType([string])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Uri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [string]$OutFile = "$PSScriptRoot\Downloaded.File"
    )
    $FileDownload = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri
    $FilePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutFile)
    if(-not $FilePath) {$FilePath = $PSScriptRoot}
    $FileName = $null
    if([bool]$FileDownload.Headers['Content-Disposition']) {
        $FileName = [System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition]::new($FileDownload.Headers["Content-Disposition"]).FileName
    } else {
        switch ($FileDownload.BaseResponse) {
            {$_ -is [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]} {
                $FileName = $FileDownload.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[-1]
            }
            {$_ -is [System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]} {
                $FileName = $FileDownload.BaseResponse.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Segments[-1]
            }
            Default {
                $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($OutFile)
            }
        }
    }
    if(-not $FileName) {$FileName = 'Downloaded.File'}
    $FileNamePath = Join-Path -Path $FilePath -ChildPath $FileName
    $File = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($FileNamePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $File.Write($FileDownload.Content, 0, $FileDownload.RawContentLength)
    $File.Close()
    Return $FileNamePath
}
$OutFilePath = Invoke-WebRequestDownload -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341'
#$OutFilePath = Invoke-WebRequestDownload -Uri 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393217'
#$OutFilePath = Invoke-WebRequestDownload -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109047&Channel=Stable&language=en&consent=1'
$OutFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to do the trick:

```
$download = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341"
$FileName = $download.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[-1]

$file = [System.IO.FileStream]::new("$PSScriptRoot\$FileName", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$file.Write($download.Content, 0, $download.RawContentLength)
$file.Close()
```

From Matthew Hodgkins [blog](https://hodgkins.io/download-file-with-powershell-without-renaming), and killingtime's link we get:

```
$download = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341"
```

But Hodgkins's code tries to use `Content-Disposition`, which does not exist in `$download`.  Looking through `$download` I eventually found that `$download.BaseResponse.ResponseUri` gives us a Uri.  Searching around for getting a filename from a Uri eventually led me to [Lee_Dailey's](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/f3mlff/comment/fhnvbl8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) use of `Segments[-1]`, giving us:

```
$FileName = $download.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[-1]
```

As for a file destination, in my case I wanted it to be the same folder as the script, so `$PSScriptRoot` was used to make a small change to Hodgkins's example.

```
$file = [System.IO.FileStream]::new("$PSScriptRoot\$FileName", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$file.Write($download.Content, 0, $download.RawContentLength)
$file.Close()
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I've run the code but it throws errors at the first line. Invoke-WebRequest is not recognised.... I assume you're running something other than PS v2.0, which is what comes with Win7 (?) thanks for the code and write up though.

Comment: @killingtime, I don't know how to recreate your situation - I don't have Win7 or PS v2.0.  A few months ago I looked into creating environments like that, but failed to find an answer.  But, here is a good question for you.  Can you download the [zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2#zip) version of PowerShell version 7 and run that version on your Windows 7 system?  I use this version a lot because it doesn't require installation - just extract to a folder and run pwsh.exe.

Comment: Downloaded the zip and ran pwsh.exe. at the command prompt, pasted the code in. 1st line worked, all others error:                                                                                                   
PS C:\Temp\ps7.2.6> $FileName = $download.BaseResponse.ResponseUri
.Segments[-1]
InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.
PS C:\Temp\ps7.2.6> $file = [System.IO.FileStream]::new("$PSScript
Root\$FileName", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Acce
ss to the path 'C:\' is denied."

Comment: What happens if you place the 5 lines of code in a script and then in the Windows command prompt pass the script as a parameter to pwsh.exe?  If you can use PowerShell 7, and no longer limited to PowerShell 2.0, then there has to be a way to get this to work, just an issue of figuring out the right way.

Comment: I tried that as well. Same errors. Not to worry. I've found a solution using wget.exe compiled for 64bit Windows. Wget has all the necessary encryption libraries compiled into the source headers, so no need to update the operating system. Thanks for all your replies and help:                                         wget.exe --user-agent="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12" -c https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87341
<CR> DEL .wget-hsts
<CR> REN "index.html@linkid=87341" update.exe

Comment: @killingtime, I know you found an answer, but I couldn't resist trying to figure out why Invoke-WebRequest was failing at times.  Finally figured out that if Content-Disposition is available, then use it to get the file name, otherwise use a URI buried in BaseResponse to get the file name, only BaseResponse is structured different in PS v5.1 than it is in PS v7.2.x, so had to deal with that too.  Anyways, posted new answer with the new code.